# Redirect to homepage if translation is not available in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a multilingual site on Drupal 7 with language links displayed and I want to be able to redirect the user to the homepage if the translation of a node is not available.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use this module: https://drupal.org/project/multilink.
The problem is that Im not sure if this module can redirect to homepage.

The best solution is to create your custom module and implementes **hook_node_view**

```
function yourmodulename_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
    // show 404 page if current language does not match content node language
   global $language;
   if (!empty($node->language) && $node->language != $language->language) {
      drupal_goto('<front>');  
   }
}
```

Im not sure if this code works, but its the correct way.

Regards.